# Test failing cases with React, Jest, React-Testing-Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a React component that throws an Error when programming is wrong. For example, the component `Component` takes the required prop `data`, and I have:

`if (!data) { throw new Error("data is not provided") }`

written in my component to handle this error. Using `jest` my test says:

```
test("throw invalid component error", () => {
    mockConsole();
    const { container } = render(<Component />);
    expect(container).toThrowError();
});
```

When I run my test Jest says that the test fails and then it points me to the line where I have my `throw new Error(...)` written. Is what I'm trying to do possible in jest?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To assert a `function` to throw an error, you have to pass a `function` to the expect statement. In your case:

```
test('...', () => {
  expect(() => {
    render(<Component />);
  }).toThrowError();
});
```

Comment: aah i wasn't wrapping the render in an `expect`, thank you!

Comment: In this way jest prints a "console.error" in console, dirtying the test log :/

Comment: Yes I'm with @DouglasNassifRomaJunior, what workaround we have to avoid that? maybe a custom error boundary per-test?
Thanks